# regular expression preg replace omit a character

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I use this function to replace relative links with absolutes and make them as parameters for the page to stream it with file_get_contents. there is a problem i think in my regular expression that omits a character
its the function

```
$pattern = "/<a([^>]*) " .
         "href=\"[^http|ftp|https|mailto]([^\"]*)\"/";
$replace = "<a\${1} href=\"?u=" . $base . "\${2}\"";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
$pattern = "/<a([^>]*) " .
         "href='[^http|ftp|https|mailto]([^\']*)'/";

$replace = "<a\${1} href=\"?u=" . $base . "\${2}\"";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
$pattern = "/<img([^>]*) " . 
         "src=\"[^http|ftp|https]([^\"]*)\"/";
$replace = "<img\${1} src=\"" . $base . "\${2}\"";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);

$pattern = "/<a([^>]*) " .
         "href=\"([^\"]*)\"/";
$replace = "<a\${1} href=\"?u=" . "\${2}\"";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

so

```
 "UsersList.aspx?dir=09"
```

with this $base url":

```
 http://www.some-url.com/Members/
```

should be replaced to

```
 "?u=http://www.some-url.com/Members/UsersList.aspx?dir=09"
```

but i get

```
 "?u=http://www.some-url.com/Members/sersList.aspx?dir=09"
```

i dont know whats the problem in my regular expression and how to fix it

Comment: `[^http|ftp|https|mailto]` doesn't do what you think it does. `[^...]` matches a SINGLE character that's not one of the characters in the brackets. So that matches a single character that isn't in `htp|fsmailo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Guess your a tag is like 

<a href="UsersList.aspx?dir=09"></a>
```

and it will not work with this pattern for your desired result.

```
$pattern = "/<a([^>]*) " . "href=\"[^http|ftp|https|mailto]([^\"]*)\"/";
```

in that

[^http|ftp|https|mailto] -- this expression matches only one character, means 'U' will be missing

try removing that like

```
$pattern = "/<a([^>]*) " . "href=\"([^\"]*)\"/";
```

Comment: of course it works. but this expression should select just relative links but not absolutes. for the absolutes it shouldnt add base url.     the part [^http|ftp|https|mailto] is responsible here to just select relative links

Comment: ok I used $pattern = "/<a([^>]*) " .
         "href=\"([^http|ftp|https|mailto][^\"]*)\"/"; and it solved

Comment: i think both are the same. are'nt they?